# Is Sexton Furnival and Mad Hettie's physical similarity intentional?

Tags: vertigo-comics, the-sandman

Why this could be the case:

- Hettie has slightly lower height than Sexton on page 27, but without her hunch they would probably be the *same height.*
- *Hettie never shows her face clearly to Sexton,* stepping forward to address Death on page 28.
- Hettie has the *same hairstyle and facial features* as Sexton on page 28. All of the other characters have very distinct faces, so this doesn't seem like a likely oversight by the artist.
- Hettie and Sexton are *both looking for their heart,* in different ways.

Why this might not be the case:

- Hettie's search is explicit, and Sexton could be said to have never searched at all.
- Hettie has other roles in the Sandman universe, none of them as a "template" character if I recall correctly. Tying her this closely to Sexton seems a bit weird.

Is there any indication that this was or wasn't intentional? And if it was intentional, what was the intent?